# How to enable built in bluetooth in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have a laptop with built in Bluetooth, Ubuntu OS and a Virtual Box. I've created a Windows 7 Virtual Machine. How can I access Bluetooth from it?

Comment: Did you tried to install guest additions ? I dont know if Virtual Box have it but it should have. Also try VmWare Player it mostly works better than Virtual Box.

Comment: I've installed VmWare, now bluetooth can be enabled, but no pair can't be established or it doesn't see anything.
Tried to install VmWare on ubuntu and on windows 7, but got the same result. 
Any ideas to make built in bluetooth work?